# Finding the minimum volume of physical interconnectivity

Tags: volume, connections

Say I have N nodes linked to each other by a flexible cable of constant radius R (even when making knots of it), how do I know the minimum volume for a complete interconnectivity (i.e. each node being connected to all other nodes by one bidirectional cable)?
Obviously, given the thickness of the cable, each node must also have a size big enough to allow every cable to plug in.

Nodes may be spherical but this is not mandatory.

This is not homework.

I have no idea where to start from. I can compute the number of cables, i.e. N times (N-1), and possibly the minimum surface of a node, i.e. R squared times Pi times (N-1) but this is approximative as circles cannot be perfectly packed.

More difficult here, is the packing of all these cables in tridimensional space. I could do it one by one, numerically, but I wonder if there is a more analytical approach to this.

Note that the position of the nodes can be freely choosen. They do not need to be located on the shell.

I did not find duplicates but I am not sure I use the right keywords.

Comment: Even with a bounty, I only get a dead room.

Comment: Do the nodes all have to be in one line (all nodes are attached to one cable) or can the network of nodes look like a tree graph?

Comment: Do the nodes form a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph)?

Comment: You are looking for graph embeddings: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding) is one type. I don't know what an answer to this question would even look like? An algorithm for placement maybe? As a *completely arbitrary* starting point, you could try placing the nodes on some different surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, filling in the connections numerically, and see what surfaces are efficient

Comment: @Tc14: if all nodes are connected to all nodes, there are broken lines passing through all nodes, but I am not sure what you are asking about.

Comment: @Sal: yes, a complete graph

Comment: @Sal: I know numerical methods to get an answer, but I was looking for a more analytical approach, if existent. Maybe the book thickness approach you are mentioning is useful here. My main problem here is making the graph solid, ie. physical, with a end volume. If you connect each node of a complete graph with incompressible thread, how much thread is required at a minimum?

Comment: Even forgetting about the connecting thread, you face something akin to a [sphere packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres). Notice the proof of this was at first 'by exhaustion', then automated. Perhaps if you specify some constraints (such as 'all nodes in a line' or 'all nodes on surface of sphere'), rather than (absolute) 'minimum volume', we could make progress

Comment: @Winston Nevermind, my question has been resolved.